# Elections polls are not conducted daily within each state. How to fill the missing days in the dataset according to the rule defined?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, data-analysis

This is an exercise question from the book QSS by Kosuke Imai, chapter 4.
The dataset is prediction of 2008 US election outcomes based on betting markets. In order to solve the exercise, I should tweak the dataset according a rule provided within the question:

"Notice that polls are not conducted daily within each state. Therefore, within a given state, for each of the last 90 days of the campaign, we compute the average margin of victory from the most recent poll(s) conducted. If multiple polls occurred on the same day, average these polls."

What I was able to do:

```
polls08 = pd.read_csv('polls08.csv')

# compute number of days to the election 
polls08['middate'] = pd.to_datetime(polls08['middate'])

polls08['days_to_election'] = (x - polls08['middate']).dt.days

# compute average margin of victory
polls08['avg_margin_of_victory'] = polls08['Obama'] - polls08['McCain']

# subsetting 90 days to the election
filtered_df4 = polls08[polls08['days_to_election'] < 90]

# grupby according to days to election and state
# here we also notice that polls are not conducted daily within each state.
filtered_df4 = filtered_df4.groupby(['days_to_election', 'state'])['avg_margin_of_victory'].mean().reset_index()
```

[image: filtered_df4_image]

I could come until this far. The author suggests:
"One strategy to answer this question is to program two loops—an inner loop with 51 iterations (for each state) and an outer loop with 90 iterations (for each day)."

I tried but couldn't to build the loop that solves according to the rule above. Instead, my mind is a mess now. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

The link to the dataset: https://github.com/kosukeimai/qss/blob/master/PREDICTION/polls08.csv

Comment: correction: the dataset is not based on betting markets but polls

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Post them as text instead.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). A sample of the dataframe should do, i.e. `print(df)`